# How to check if in checkout if custom module installed?

Tags: onepage-checkout

I am developing a module that will inject template into footer. Inside that template I need to check if current page is cart or onepage or other page. I could check if current page is onepage with this code

```
if($request->getActionName()=="onepage")
```

But if a website is using custom module (which I can not know in advance, onestepcheckout for example), how can I check it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, really. When it comes to extensions for mass distribution, your best bet is to program them against a stock Magento system, and then setup a solid support system that allows your users/customers to get support if they run into the scenario you describe.  So many Magento extensions rely on extending the system in unofficial ways that you'll go nuts trying to keep up. As your extension becomes more popular you'll start to see which extensions cause the most problem, and add some hard-coded exceptions for those. If enough people are using your extension for this to happen, that's a nice problem to have.

That said, if I was going to attempt an implementation of this, I'd start by looking into the `getOriginalPathInfo` method on the request object.

```
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getOriginalPathInfo()
```

I'd also consider trying to get a reference to the actual controller object used, and then using something like [is_a](http://php.net/is_a) to check if the controller object inherits from the standard Checkout controller (which many of the one page checkout modules do).

Answer (score 1):

In your custom module config.xml you could only enable your module if another module is enable by using `<depends>`

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <MagePal_CimPaymentPro>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Payment />
            </depends>
        </MagePal_CimPaymentPro>
    </modules>
```

Or see [Determine if Magento module is enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551846/determine-if-magento-module-is-enabled)

```
Mage::helper('core')->isModuleEnabled(<module name>);
Mage::getConfig()->getModuleConfig('modulename')->is('active', 'true')
```

To check if your on `checkout` you could try `Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()`